# C# and crystalreport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've written a C# project with Crystal Reports. I'm building a setup project but I get an error:

> The indirectly-referenced assembly
>   'BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could not be found.
>   This assembly is not required for analysis, however, analysis results
>   could be incomplete. This assembly was referenced by: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework
>   4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalRepor ts.Engine.dll

Comment: Is that a Web Application or Forms application? Does your setup project include Crystal Reports Runtime installer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Crystal Reports merge modules for the version of Crystal Reports you are using in your C# project. Don't "auto detect" or any other manual or approximated addition of the files needed. You should **absolutely** find and add the merge modules from here:

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp

Comment: Ricky, that link used to go to a great comprehensive list of the various Crystal Reports versions - bundled .NET as well as full versions.

That's still the task; To match your version to the files from the website. Here are two links that map many of the versions to merge modules:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms225284(v=vs.80).aspx

http://scn.sap.com/thread/2120514

Once you have a good sense of what version you are using, you can search for the files themselves. Either by file name, or by keywords like 'crystal reports xi merge modules' or 'crystal reports xi redist'.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! SAP seems to break their own links all the time. 90 % of Stack Overflow links I click on that relates to SAP are broken.